# property 'length' of undefined Jade - simple loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am rendering a jade template using a query from mongoDB through node.

Express is handling my get using...

```
app.get('/rendered', function(req, res){
    console.log(mongoDoc[0].date + " date 0");
    console.log(mongoDoc[1].date + " date 1");
    res.render('renderMe', mongoDoc);
});
```

The mongoDB

```
{
        "date" : "1-May-12",
        "close" : "58.13"
}
{
        "date" : "1-Apr-12",
        "close" : "18.13"
}
```

The Jade Template **(Very new to this!**)

```
for result in mongoDoc
     p #{result.date}
```

Am I using Jade incorrectly? Are there some good tutorials out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the mongoDoc array to your template, use JSON.stringify and then parse it as JSON in your template

```
app.get('/rendered', function(req, res){
    console.log(mongoDoc[0].date + " date 0");
    console.log(mongoDoc[1].date + " date 1");
    res.render('renderMe', {mongoDoc: JSON.stringify(mongoDoc)});
});
```

And inside your template

```
var mongoDoc= JSON.parse('!{mongoDoc}');
for result in mongoDoc
    p #{result.date}
```

Edit: Try to render your data in this way

```
each result in mongoDoc
    p= result.date
```

Comment: Thank you, it is printing in the template. It is however a long JSON string, even after using p#{result.date}, is there anyway to parse it? Also, looking at the elements, the <var></var> element is created, and a bunch of <p> tags that are empty.

Comment: mongoDoc= JSON.parse('[{"_id":"id1","date":"1-May-12","close":"58.13"},{"_id":"id2","date":"1-Apr-12","close":"18.13"}]');

Comment: Did you try removing `var` from `var mongoDoc..` ?

Comment: Yes, it then spits out a <mongoDoc> tag and a bunch of empty <p> tags

Comment: The indentation reflects the answer you provided

Comment: Is that your entire Jade template?

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes

Comment: I have edited my answer. See if there's any changes.

Comment: The page is now empty, no errors are thrown. There is a bunch of <p> tags however the Database only has 3 entries in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81887/discussion-between-dnwebdev-and-bidhan-a).